# Using jquery from partial view received from jquery-ui tabs

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a page that has tabs on it using jquery-ui. The tabs are loaded via ajax.

```
@foreach (var data in Model)
{
            <li role="presentation">
                <a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href='@Url.Action("Detail", "Changes", new { grouping = data.Grouping })'>@data.Name<br /> (@data.Type)</a>
            </li>
}
```

**Inside the partial view that gets loaded I have some buttons that I need to be able to trap the click event for but they aren't getting called.**

Partial view

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#btnKeepCurrent").click(function () {
                alert("Keep Current");

                return false;
            });

            $("#btnAcceptNew").click(function () {
                alert("Accept New");

                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
}

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Keep Current" name="btnKeepCurrent" id="btnKeepCurrent" />

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Accept New" name="btnAcceptNew" id="btnAcceptNew" />
```

Comment: In fact nothing gets called in the partial view inside the $(function(){});

Answer (score 0):

set onlick attribute on those inputs, because like you are doing now:

```
 $(function () {
 //set on click here
}
```

this function is called on document ready, but since the tab is loading this using ajax this function will not be called ever.

so instead of this:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Keep Current" name="btnKeepCurrent" id="btnKeepCurrent" />
```

try this:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" onclick="alert('put your function call insead of this alert')" type="button" value="Keep Current" name="btnKeepCurrent" id="btnKeepCurrent" />
```